# Ruby on Rails: link-to using post method but parameters are in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm using

```
link_to 'My link', path(:arg1 => session[:arg1], :arg2 => session[:arg2],:arg3 => anyobject.id), :method => :post
```

but the HTML link being generated includes (arg1,arg2,arg3) as [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) query parameters.

How can remove them? Did I miss something in the documentation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `link_to` will always put the arguments into the query string as it is creating a get-style HTML link - even if you put `:method => :post` that just appends an extra ("special") argument `_method`.

What I think you really want is a `button_to` link - which will make it into a sort of form-post. It works the same, but it says `button_to` instead (for example, `button_to 'My link', path(:params => :go_here)`. The downside is that it will look like a button. But you can give it a CSS class (eg "unbutton") and then change the styling on that CSS class to make it not look like a button.

Alternatively, if what you really want is actually to have no `params` passed to the controller at all... then just don't include them when making your link (for example, `link_to "My link" path` - there's no need for `:post` if you don't want to post any `params`).

Finally, if what you want is for the `params` to become a part of the URL (for example, `stuff/[param_1]/more_stuff/[param_2]`, etc.) then you need to update your routes to include these parameters as options. Have a look at the routing section of the [rdoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html) for how to do that.

Comment: This solution has taken me hours of googling! I'm new to Rails. button_to fixed my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Update on that: 4.1 ships button_to with a params parameter (with the gotcha that it does not allow nested parameters, *dough*), where the parameters are really constructed using hidden fields. That is probably what you want.

Comment: Neato... well - my advice still stands for past Rails, but good to see they've finally got a solution of some kind out there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code, which [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L118) need data-method to switch to post mode in Ajax.

`<%= link_to '<button id="print" type="submit" class="btn">Print</button>'.html_safe, { controller: :lots, id: @lot.containername, action: "print_#{print_template}", remote: true },  {'data-method' => :post} %>`