# button_to that submits post with params to create record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have a button or link that will create a vote, I gather I have to use a post so I am using button_to, my current code is just adding the :song and :user_id to the  button element itself, and thus not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="plusvote"><%= button_to '+', {:controller => "votes", :action => "create"}, :song => song.id, :user=> session[:user_id] , :method=>:post  %></td>
    <td><%= song.votes.count %></td>
    <td><%= song.name %></td>
    <td><%= song.code %></td>
    <td><%= song.album %></td>
<% end %>
```

There is no error, the button/form when pressed/submitted just won't post correctly because the generated html is:

```
<form action="/votes" class="button_to" method="post">
    <div>
        <input song="5" type="submit" user="1" value="+" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="tucB4fQ4XbrnzF3lFcQnMq/1rSaPrcsc/tFJ1SQttns=" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is use rails classic `form_for` helper, but set input type to `hidden` for each attribute. Also you'll need to set up default value for each input (as far as I see there are only one – `:song`). And then change button_to to usual submit button.

Comment: I thought about this but also figured there must be a better method

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you simply have put the :song and :user_id values outside the url hash.  Try replacing your button with this:

```
<%= button_to '+', {:controller => "votes", :action => "create", :song => song.id, :user=> session[:user_id]}, :method=>:post  %>
```

Comment: In that case the parameters are added onto the url, I want a post

Comment: in rails there is no difference between parameters added to the URL and parameters posted

Comment: If it's the look of the url that bothers you then you need to use Nick's suggestion of using form_for.

Comment: "in rails there is no difference between parameters added to the URL and parameters posted" I just don't think this is accurate

Comment: ALso this post seems to suggest it can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353929/ruby-on-rails-link-to-using-post-method-but-parameters-are-in-the-url

Comment: @A_funs It is accurate in the sense that both parameters in the url and those posted get merged in to the "params" variable